# Determine P(D|C,F) from P(D), P(F) and P(C|D,F)

Tags: probability, bayesian

How do I determine $P(A|B,C)$ when the following is known: $P(A)$, $P(C)$, $P(B|A,C)$

I do understand the Bayes theorem that states:
$P(A|B,C) = P(A,B|C)/P(B|C)$

However, I am failing to see how I can rearrange my given probabilities to work out the answer using Bayes or probability addition/multiplication rules.

Comment: It looks like you will have inherent difficulties finding $P(A,C)$ from $P(A)$ and $P(C)$ alone unless you make a strong assumption such as independence. A similar remark applies to $B$ and $C.$ This suggests you refocus your strategy to finding a counterexample: that is, can you find a simple probability space, events $A,B,C,$ and two different probability distributions with the same known values of $P(A),$ $P(C),$ and $P(B\mid A,C)$ but different values of $P(A\mid B,C)$?